# insert vector element from vector's element member method destroys *this

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, push-back

Can someone explain me why this C++ code it's behaving this way?
And .. how can i avoid this 'vector' problems in the future.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct my_str {
    int x;
    my_str() {
        x = 0;
    }
    void insert();
};
vector<my_str> p;

void my_str :: insert() {
    p.push_back(my_str());
    x = 123;
}

int main() {
    p.push_back(my_str());
    p[0].insert();
    cerr << p[0].x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "destroys `*this`"? What about this code's behaviour is confusing you?

Comment: @delnan: I suppose the fact that this displays "0", not "123" (http://ideone.com/jyagJK).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p.push_back(my_str());` in `void my_str :: insert()`

causes vector reallocation, `this` is invalid

```
x = 123;
```

BOOM! Heap corruption.

To avoid such problems in future do not edit vectors from objects they contain.
Or, if you have to, make sure you do not use object members after this.

Comment: This happened when i implemented a trie class .. 
For that i prefere to use vectors in favor of the clasic pointer childrens (because pointers are slower) .. is my aproach so wrong?

Comment: If you need your own tree in vector that bad - just modify vector after all object's members modifications. And remember that all pointers are potentially invalid (you can use only indexes). And be careful.

Comment: @AlexVelea Alternatively, you could change the `vector<my_str>` into `vector<unique_ptr<my_str>>`. This might make more sense because if you're storing all your trie nodes in a vector, you'll have to copy around the nodes on every reallocation which could potentially be quite expensive if you're storing a large data type in each node. It makes more sense to allocate the nodes separately, and use a vector of pointers to manage the ordering.